# HTTPS to HTTP using CherryPy

Tags: python, http, https, wsgi, cherrypy

Is it possible for CherryPy to redirect HTTP to HTTPS. Lets for example say the code below is http://example.com if someone visits via https://example.com I want them to be redirected to the plain HTTP URL (301 redirect maybe?) how do I accomplish this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pprint import pformat
from cherrypy import wsgiserver

def app(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain')]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return [pformat(environ)]

server = wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 80), app)

try:
    server.start()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    server.stop()
```

Comment: Why do this in CherryPy when Apache can do it more efficiently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the `request.scheme` if it is "https" then you can raise a redirect.

See https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/blob/f185ecd005d7fdbafb0ed83b0e49f05ac76e43fd/cherrypy/_cprequest.py#L218

Comment: I guess this is the new one valid link: https://tools.ietf.org/doc/python-cherrypy3/api/cherrypy._cprequest.Request-class.html

Comment: thanks @kolinko - I have gone with the github link.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew Cox's link is broken again, here's the updated link to it. I don't have enough points to comment on his answer, hence the new answer.

https://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/3.3.0/refman/_cprequest.html#cherrypy._cprequest.Request.scheme