# SSL not working in CherryPy

Tags: ssl, cherrypy

I've seemingly done everything according to docs but SSL just does not work.
Here's my CherryPy `settings.conf`:

```
[global]
request.show_tracebacks = False
server.socket_port = 443
server.thread_pool = 10
log.screen = True
log.error_file = '/root/website/Web.log'
log.access_file = '/root/website/Access.log'
cherrypy.server.ssl_module = 'pyopenssl'
cherrypy.server.ssl_certificate = "/etc/ssl/website/AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt"
cherrypy.server.ssl_private_key = "/etc/ssl/website/btcontract_com.key"
cherrypy.server.ssl_certificate_chain = "/etc/ssl/website/chain.crt"
```

If I try to load `site.com:443` in browser it works without using a certificate.
If I try `https://site.com` the browser says there's an SSL connect error.

`CherryPy` error and connection logs contain nothing at all as if it does not even getting these `https` requests. I'm not sure if my python has built in SSL support so I did installed `pyOpenSSL`. What's going on and how can I fix this?

Comment: `btcontract.com:443` is undoubtedly doing a plain http requests, since you're not telling the browser to use https. Without forcing the protcol by using the `https://...` protocol prefix on the url, the browser will use plain http - just because you're hitting 443 won't magically convert that plain request to https. so.. ssl isn't working on your server.

Comment: @MarcB OK, thanks. Sadly this does not solve my problem.

Comment: I have nginx in front of cherrypy which handles the https redirect.  check this answer out... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237830/https-to-http-using-cherrypy

Comment: @AndrewKloos why use nginx if CherryPy supposedly can handle HTTPS by itself?

Comment: nginx does some request throttling, handles ssl and serves static content.  My biggest reason is that nginx handles DOS attacks well without disrupting non-offending clients.

Comment: @AndrewKloos another good reason to use a front-end is to be able to use a privileged port (such as 443) without running as root (although you could do this with the DropPrivileges plugin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a change in version 3.2.5 that broke SSL support. This hasn't been fixed yet (as of version 3.6.0), but there is a patch suggested in [issue 1298](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/issue/1298/ssl-not-working) if you need to use one of these versions.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by installing a lower version on CherryPy (namely 3.2.3). Apparently something is wrong with SSL in 3.6.0